# sqlite3_bind_text for null string

Tags: cocoa, sqlite

I use the codes to access sqlite

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement,1,[myString UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

It works. 
But if myString is NULL, it always causes updating the record in table failed.
(or nothing changed)
How to process when myStrign is NULL?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: You set **NOT NULL** for that field while you created the table in sqlite?

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `sqlite3_bind_null(statement, 1);` when your string is NULL.

```
if (myString)
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement,1,[myString UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
else 
    sqlite3_bind_null(statement,1);
```

Comment: Doug please take a look at this similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462951/ios-sqlite3-statement-coalesce-causing-memory-problems