# ios: using the same sqlite parameter more than once causes premature memory deallocation

Tags: objective-c, sql, sqlite, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

**Note:**
the question is misleading.. i *thought* it was using more than one parameter that causes a memory error.. but that's not the reason.. the reason was an incorrectly formed sql statement.. see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534957/766570) below.

if create an sqlite statement that uses the same parameter more than once ie

```
    NSString* updateStmt = @"INSERT INTO search_email(..., subject, ...)"
    " SELECT ..., :subject, ...,"
    " coalesce((SELECT search_email.threadID "
    " FROM search_email "
    " WHERE search_email.subject MATCH :subject2 "
    " ),"
    " :uid"
    " )";

int subjectIndex = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(searchEmailInsertStmt,":subject");
int subjectIndex2 = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(searchEmailInsertStmt,":subject2");

...    
sqlite3_bind_text(searchEmailInsertStmt, subjectIndex, [subject UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);        // subject
sqlite3_bind_text(searchEmailInsertStmt, subjectIndex2, [subjectCopy UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);        // search_email.subject


if (sqlite3_step(searchEmailInsertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSLog(@"Failed step in searchEmailInsertStmt: '%s', '%i'", sqlite3_errmsg([[AddEmailDBAccessor sharedManager] database]), pk);
}
```

then it crashes with the following error:
`malloc: *** error for object 0x9b6350: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

any idea why?

**update:**
if i replace subject and subjectCopy with string constants ie @"subject1" and @"subject2" it works just fine.. but for some reason i tried duplicating this programmatically ie

```
NSString* subjectCopy = [NSString alloc];
subjectCopy = [subject retain];
```

and none of those work.. also changing SQLITE_TRANSIENT to SQLITE_STATIC has no effect.

**update 2:** output of bt after breaking at malloc_error_break:

```
thread #6: tid = 0x2503, 0x99a20815 libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x99a20815 libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break
frame #1: 0x99a21d51 libsystem_c.dylib`free + 346
frame #2: 0x0005d5e8 reMail`sqlite3MemFree + 40 at sqlite3.c:12272
frame #3: 0x0002a53e reMail`sqlite3_free + 126 at sqlite3.c:15653
frame #4: 0x0004e670 reMail`sqlite3Fts3ExprFree + 64 at sqlite3.c:101490
frame #5: 0x0004e665 reMail`sqlite3Fts3ExprFree + 53 at sqlite3.c:101489
frame #6: 0x0003fbf1 reMail`fulltextClose + 49 at sqlite3.c:97401
frame #7: 0x000b48f3 reMail`sqlite3VdbeFreeCursor + 163 at sqlite3.c:47461
frame #8: 0x000aebb8 reMail`sqlite3VdbeExec + 17576 at sqlite3.c:54042
frame #9: 0x00032273 reMail`sqlite3Step + 467 at sqlite3.c:49459
frame #10: 0x00031f5e reMail`sqlite3_step + 78 at sqlite3.c:49531
frame #11: 0x000ff2ae reMail`-[EmailProcessor insertIntoSearch:withMetaString:withUid:withSubject:withBody:withFrom:withTo:withCc:withFolder:] + 1854 at EmailProcessor.m:934
frame #12: 0x001005a1 reMail`-[EmailProcessor addEmail:] + 3153 at EmailProcessor.m:1015
frame #13: 0x000fd673 reMail`-[EmailProcessor addEmailWrapper:] + 4035 at EmailProcessor.m:651
frame #14: 0x0324c1bd CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 29
frame #15: 0x0324c0d6 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 342
frame #16: 0x017c36b5 Foundation`-[NSInvocationOperation main] + 45
frame #17: 0x01738d23 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal start] + 736
frame #18: 0x01738a34 Foundation`-[NSOperation start] + 79
frame #19: 0x017c5301 Foundation`__block_global_6 + 150
frame #20: 0x02ec053f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
frame #21: 0x02ed2014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
frame #22: 0x02ec32e8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 335
frame #23: 0x02ec3450 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
frame #24: 0x99a09e12 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 441
```

Comment: Why are you using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`?

Comment: `:1,$s/SQLITE_TRANSIENT/0/g` Would do it I reckon.

Comment: i have no idea lol.. that code was copied from the folks who did the [remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) email client.. but i'm curious about to implement what you suggested.. the final thing would look something like this `sqlite3_bind_text(searchEmailInsertStmt, 8, [folder UTF8String], -1, :1,$s/SQLITE_TRANSIENT/0/g);`?

Comment: you can't make such a command as part of a sqlite3_bind_text statement

Comment: Sorry; my jokey comment is a `vi` command to replace all occurrences of `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` with `0`.  There is no need for sqlite to copy the bind values as the statement is executed immediately.

Comment: just tried it.. unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Do what the error message tells you: set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`.  (You can do that by going to the Breakpoint Navigator, Command-6, then clicking the + button at the bottom, and choosing Add Symbolic Breakpoint.  Set the symbol to `malloc_error_break` and leave the other fields alone.)  Then run the app.  When it stops in the debugger, type `bt` in the debug console.  Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it! after chasing so many red herrings.. the best advice i got was [on a forum specialized for sqlite](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/using-the-same-sqlite-parameter-more-than-once-causes-premature-memory-deallocation-td66687.html#a66718): the point was to keep the guts of sqlite out of my debugging reach, it's extremely unlikely that it's sqlite's fault.

i basically decided to break my sql statement into smaller pieces and run each on it's own:

**original sql statement that caused the memory problem:**

```
    NSString* updateStmt = @"INSERT INTO search_email(docid, meta, subject, body, sender, tos, ccs, folder, threadid)"
    " SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,"
    " coalesce((SELECT search_email.threadID "
    " FROM search_email "
    " WHERE search_email.subject MATCH ?  UNION SELECT * FROM "
    " (SELECT threadID FROM  (SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.sender MATCH ? "
    " INTERSECT SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.tos MATCH ? ) "
    "  UNION "
    " SELECT threadID FROM (SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.sender MATCH ? "
    "       INTERSECT SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.tos MATCH ?)) "
    " LIMIT 1"
    " ),"
    " ?"
    " )";
```

the problem happened whenever i supplied strings with special characters to match..
the following are examples of problematic parameters sent to MATCH:

*sabaho :)

New core-audio questions for Feb 1 - Stack Exchange

Ref; Data Centric testing/ETL Tester oppurtunity at Chicago, IL.*

so to go around that i simply replaced MATCH with a normal `=` comparison.. but cleaned up the parameter using regex first:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"re:(\\s)*"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];


                            error:&error];

NSString *filteredSubjectFromRe = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:subject
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])
                                                             withTemplate:@""];

if(searchEmailInsertStmt == nil) {

    NSString* updateStmt = @"INSERT INTO search_email(docid, meta, subject, body, sender, tos, ccs, folder, threadid)"
    " SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,"
    " coalesce((SELECT search_email.threadID "
    " FROM search_email "
    " WHERE search_email.subject = ? UNION SELECT * FROM "
    " (SELECT threadID FROM  (SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.sender = ? "
    " INTERSECT SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.tos = ? ) "
    "  UNION "
    " SELECT threadID FROM (SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.sender = ? "
    "       INTERSECT SELECT threadID FROM search_email WHERE search_email.tos = ?)) "
    " LIMIT 1"
    " ),"
    " ?"
    " )";
```